# Smart way to check if problem is solvable by using double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In a famous double slit experiment if you make observations of particles, but then delete the data not looking at it, it will happen that light acted as a particle. My question is, what if we didn't delete the data but put it into some storage that would accept as password only the correct proof that P = NP. I assume that it can correctly check the proofs. Then we look, if light acted as a particle then P = NP is impossible to prove, i.e data is not recoverable. If we assume that this experiment is possible to make, would it make sense?

Comment: That's not how qm "works".

Comment: @zabop where did I go wrong then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

- You're mixing up a conscious observer and an observer.
- It's not about 'deleting data,' it's more about 'over-writing' it. If you try to detect which slit the photon went through, then literally delete the data, you'll still get a clump pattern.
- To get an interference pattern, the photons cannot be entangled with the detectors. If you attempt to figure out which slit the photon goes through, you're essentially entangling the detector with the photon. For an interference pattern, you cannot have that entanglement.